# unexpected variable

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
$mail = filter_var(trim($_POST['mail']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$pass = md5($pass."asdpixcvn23Qc;ljx")

$query = "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE `mail` = '$mail' AND `pass` = '$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

while($user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($mail==$user['mail'] && $pass==$user['pass']){
 echo 'takoj uze estj';
}else{
 echo 'takogo nety';
 }  


header('Location: reg.html');

?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точки с запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете заменить

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE `mail` = '$mail' AND `pass` = '$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

while($user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($mail==$user['mail'] && $pass==$user['pass']){
 echo 'takoj uze estj';
}else{
 echo 'takogo nety';
 }
```

на вот это

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM  `users` WHERE `mail` = '$mail' AND `pass` = '$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)));

if($result['count'] === 0){
  echo 'takogo nety';
}else{
  echo 'takoj uze estj';
}
```

Вроде так, сообщите мне если мой код содержит ошибку.